# What is datatype of cin

Tags: c++, cin

I would like to know what cin exactly is. I mean a function or class....

I am sure it not a function as the way we use cin is very different from the a function is called.

That leaves options like class or object or something else.

What is it exactly?

Comment: Internet is your friend... `cin` is an object of `istream` class type. Try `type of cin` on your favorite search engine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin` is an ***object*** of the `istream` class

Comment: *`istream`, not `iostream`

Comment: Not `iostream`. It is an object of `istream`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ Standard `§27.4.1 [iostream.objects.overview]`

> ```
> #include <ios>
> #include <streambuf>
> #include <istream>
> #include <ostream>
>
> namespace std {
>   extern istream cin;
>   extern ostream cout;
>   extern ostream cerr;
>   extern ostream clog;
>   extern wistream wcin;
>   extern wostream wcout;
>   extern wostream wcerr;
>   extern wostream wclog;
> }
> ```
>
> p1 The header  declares objects that associate objects with
>   the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in
>    (27.9.2), and includes all the headers necessary to use these
>   objects.

You may also take a look at gcc's [implementation on github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/globals_io.cc#L58):

> ```
> namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
> {
> _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
>
>   // Standard stream objects.
>   // NB: Iff <iostream> is included, these definitions become wonky.
>   typedef char fake_istream[sizeof(istream)]
>   __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(istream))));
>   typedef char fake_ostream[sizeof(ostream)]
>   __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(ostream))));
>   fake_istream cin;
>   fake_ostream cout;
>   fake_ostream cerr;
>   fake_ostream clog;
>
> #ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
>   typedef char fake_wistream[sizeof(wistream)]
>   __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(wistream))));
>   typedef char fake_wostream[sizeof(wostream)]
>   __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(wostream))));
>   fake_wistream wcin;
>   fake_wostream wcout;
>   fake_wostream wcerr;
>   fake_wostream wclog;
> #endif
>
> _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
> } // namespace
> ```